# AWK: how to rewrite contents of a column but preserve the header

Tags: linux, awk

I have a very large dataset that I need to manipulate before uploading to a server. The contents of the file are in csv format and the headings must be preserved to ensure the data can match the upload database.

I did some searching on how to change the values of a specific column, and found this:

```
awk -F, '{$467=0 ; print $467}'
```

however that overwrites the column heading.
Is there a way to do this without overwriting the column heading???

Comment: Do you mean that you don't want to do any substitutions on the first line?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: I'm not following what you're trying to do: this code just prints out a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: Note that when you update a field's value, the $0 value (i.e. the current line) is rewritten using the current output field separator. You'll want to invoke the script like `awk -F, -v OFS=, ...`

Comment: I am downloading a cvs file from one server, I need to set all the values of one column to zero without changing the header value which is Stock_qty. Right now, the above script overwites everything including the header row which prevents this file from being uploaded because the column names don't match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will save the first line and change all values of 467 field

```
awk -F, 'NR>1 {$467=0}1' OFS=, file
```

NR The total number of input records seen so far(line number)

Everything in awk has the form condition{action}. If the condition evaluates to 1 then the action is performed. If the condition is omitted then the default condition is 1, so the action is performed. If the action is omitted then - if the condition is 1 - the default action is performed, which is {print $0}, which is "print the record", by default a line of the input file.
There is just a condition with the default action

So
1 or any other nonzero number means literally {print $0}

Thanks @glenn_jackman, added OFS

Comment: what does the 1 represent after the right parenthesis??   ... 0}1

Comment: @Mike, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20262869/why-does-1-in-awk-print-the-current-line

Comment: @Mike The `1` evaluates to _true_ and therefore invokes the default action, which is to output the current record. In this case, it may be modified by the previous block.

Comment: Thank you this appears to be exactly what I was looking for! :)

Comment: hmmm... this works well to prevent editing the column names, but when I redirect the output to a new file, I get a file with no column names.... how do I get the column names preserved when I output the changes?????

Comment: nevermind, I figured it out... to keep the column names... I output the first column to a new file... then append the output of the above command to the new file... works like magic!       head -n1 old.csv > new.csv    then append the data... awk -F, 'NR>1 {$467=0 ; print $0}' OFS=, >> new.csv

Comment: ```cat file | awk -F, -vOFS=, 'NR>1 {$467=0}1'```

Comment: @Mike no , [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607218/awk-how-to-rewrite-contents-of-a-column-but-preserve-the-header#comment1133341_607223) is definitely not what you do.

Comment: @nezabudka [that](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/607218/awk-how-to-rewrite-contents-of-a-column-but-preserve-the-header#comment1133342_607223) is a UUOC and making your code gawk-only (due to no space after `-v`) and assigning 2 variables separately to the same value. Do `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} NR>1 {$467=0}1' file` instead